# JavaScript / Openlayers / QGIS - Receiving Uncaught Typeerror Cannot Read Property 'WMS' of Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, openlayers-3, qgis

I am trying to connect my QGIS Project files ( maps ) that I have created into a template and use Openlayers to open it and frame it.  I enter the script below and kept on receiving a "Uncaught TypeError Cannot Read Property 'WMS' of Undefined".  I admit, I am still new to both QGIS and Openlayers, and from what I have read the code should work to try to display my maps.  I have listed the code below but please be aware for safety purposes I have replaced the map url a bit cause I don't think its the url but my coding of some sort.

Here is the scripts at the header of my page:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.3.4/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.3.4/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
  <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.3.4/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>
```

Here is my code within the body which i have trimmed the fat done trying to go basic and make it work.  Still receiving "Uncaught typeerror connot reap property 'WMS' of undefined" :

```
<div class="entry-content" style="color:#000000;">
    <a class="skiplink" href="#map">Go to map</a>
    <div id="map" class="map" tabindex="0"></div>
    <script>
        var map = new OpenLayers.layer.wms("visitation", "http://example/map/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?MAP=mapping.qgs", {
            layers: 'basic'
        });
    </script>

</div>
```

I even tried this script at first cause I wanted to add things from openlayers and see how it work but still same error...

```
<script>
    var map = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS('visitation', 'http://example/map/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?MAP=mapping.qgs', {
        layers: 'visitation',
        target: 'map',
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
                attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                collapsible: false
            })
        }),
        view: new ol.View({
             center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 2
        })
    });

    document.getElementById('zoom-out').onclick = function() {
        var view = map.getView();
        var zoom = view.getZoom();
        view.setZoom(zoom - 1);
    };

    document.getElementById('zoom-in').onclick = function() {
        var view = map.getView();
        var zoom = view.getZoom();
        view.setZoom(zoom + 1);
     };
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are using OpenLayers 4.3.4 library, while the script acts as you are using the old 2.0 version. See the official example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-image.html

Comment: Is there a way to just pop in the qgis project files (like the old version did) instead of popping in the image?

Comment: Ok that seem to work a bit better.  Still having issues with openlayers.  Will create new question